# Creating local temp table in vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I would like to create local temp table in vertica and be able to insert values into it. This is what I have so far:

```
DROP TABLE DOMAINS_FLAG;

CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE DOMAINS_FLAG (domain_name VARCHAR, pub_ats_id INT)

INSERT INTO DOMAINS_FLAG 
    (domain_name, pub_ats_id)
VALUES ('vs.com', 123555)

select * from DOMAINS_FLAG
```

I would like my output to be:

```
domain_name | pub_ats_id

  vs.com      123555
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is your question then?

Comment: How to insert? When I select * from DOMAINS_FLAG, I can only see column names.

Comment: you should `commit` after `insert` to see the rows.

Comment: Could you please show the syntax for that?

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are missing is `on commit preserve rows`. If you change your create syntax to the following:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE DOMAINS_FLAG (domain_name VARCHAR, pub_ats_id INT) on commit preserve rows;
```

Then that should solve your problem (assuming you have auto-commit on since I don't see any commit statements).

Answer (score 1):

Just put `COMMIT;` after the `INSERT` statement. It should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO DOMAINS_FLAG (domain_name, pub_ats_id)
    VALUES ('vs.com', 123555);
COMMIT;
```